# Qt Creator - Add source directories for reverse engineering

Tags: qt-creator, reverse-engineering

I'm using Qt creator as a visual interface for gdb to reverse engineer an open source app running on a remote (embedded) device. 
The app is build using automake and doesn't have a .pro file and neither do the libraries it uses.

I would like to do static analysis of the code and am looking for a simple way to jump to function declarations for the library functions.

For example, I find a library function call press F2 (Shotcut for follow symbol under cursor) and that brings me to the header file.

Is there a way to include the library source directories without creating a .pro file for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can import a Autotools project into QtCreator as explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-projects-autotools.html):

1. Enable the Autotools Plugin: `Help > About Plugins > Build Systems > AutotoolsProjectManager`
2. Restart QtCreator
3. Open **Makefile.am** throught `File > Open File or Project`